# How can I show button over map fragment activity

Tags: android, android-studio, google-maps, android-layout, android-fragments

I am using map api in my android project to catch current location and mark position I want when it successfully catches current position and then a button should be visible which says Proceed Next and when user press that it goes to next activity.
In normal activity I can I know we have visibility attribute but how to do in map fragment ?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MapsActivity" >
</fragment>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap map fragment inside `RelativeLayout` and add a button after map fragment

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <fragment
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <!--Button appears over the map and you can position within it's parent view and toggle the visibility from the code-->
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/proceed_btn"
        android:text="Proceed"

        <!--Remove comment if you want the button to be hidden by default-->
        <!-- android:visibility="gone" -->

        <!--Align to the right-->
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"

        <!--Align at the bottom-->
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
<RealtiveLayout>
```

to obtain this.

Comment: How I manage this code?? <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MapsActivity" >
</fragment>

Answer (score 0):

You can create the button inside the  and set visibility by default false when your current location is fetched then set the button visibility true;

```
<fragment 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/map"
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.LocationChooser">


<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="right|bottom"
    android:text="Next" 
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"/>
```